# error: Missing `#[pallet::config]` error on POE tutorial

Tags: rust, substrate

I know this is probably an easy one, but not for a Rust and Substrate newbie.

I am trying to implement the POE template from the substrate tutorials. [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/proof-of-existence/)

When I try to compile the template/lib.rs with the additional POE functions and enums it errors with the following.

When I try to compile using `cargo build --release`

```
     error: Missing `#[pallet::config]`
  --> /Users/pavlos/projects/substrate-node/substrate-node- 
  template/runtime/src/lib.rs:12:1
    |
 12 | / pub mod pallet {
 13 | |     use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
 14 | |     use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
 15 | |     use sp_std::vec::Vec; // Step 3.1 will include this in `Cargo.toml`
    |
 94 | |     }
 95 | | }
    | |_^

 error: could not compile `node-template-runtime` due to previous error
```

I don't understand the micro exists above `pub mod pallet {}`

```
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    use sp_std::vec::Vec;

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as 
    frame_system::Config>::Event>;
}
```

EDITED

Comment: In [this pallet template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/8e5c1c4855fe243e4b2c11880393e1abd4e11e31/pallets/template/src/lib.rs) the config trait is inside the module. You could try moving the config inside your module.

Comment: @forgetso I updated the question. It wasn't well described. The config macro is within the module.

Comment: I have cross-checked with the tutorials repo and what I have is identical. [substrate](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/compare/latest...tutorials/solutions/proof-of-existence?expand=1)

Comment: Are you using the [node](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/master/node) mentioned in the tutorials?

Comment: @forgetso yes I used the reference repo on the tutorial which didn't work. But I tried the org node-template, as posted in my answer and it works fine.  I was missing this ` use frame_support::{dispatch::DispatchResult, pallet_prelude::*};`

Answer (score 2):

Use the substrate node template (org) and not the repo reference mentioned in the tutorial.

Difference being the included crate declarations:

```
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::{dispatch::DispatchResult, pallet_prelude::*};
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    use sp_std::vec::Vec;
```

Use this [one](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/pallets/template/src/lib.rs)

Run `cargo check -p node-template-runtime` each time you make a change, to catch any issues incrementally.